# sublime text build error - prints weird codes infront

Tags: python, build, sublimetext3

I'm having some weird issue when running sublime text to build .py files. Here's a screenshot and my build system.

[image: Screenshot]

```
{
"shell_cmd": "/usr/bin/env python3 ${file}",
"selector": "source.python",
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
"working_dir": "${file_path}"
}
```

I've tried :

1. editting my python.sublime-build file
2. making a new python3.sublime-build file

How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: you could try setting the `TERM` and/or `LS_COLORS` env vars in the build system, as per https://superuser.com/a/267176/511640, or install https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ANSIescape

Comment: I'm new to programming, could you please give more details on how? I'm sorry I feel like I'm bugging the heck out of you